# One gulp task file pr theme

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

Wondering what would be the best way to accomplish this.

I have multiple themes in my web app, let's say:

```
/themes/theme_one/
/themes/theme_two/
… etc.
```

And I don't want to write one big gulp file that handles all of these. Instead I would like to be able to just write `gulp theme_one`, and that would run all gulp tasks associated with that theme automatically.

I have realized that what I am really doing is creating a shortcut for `gulp --gulpfile themes/theme_one/gulpfile.js`

I was thinking a root Gulpfile.js that was something like this:

```
var gulp   = require('gulp');
var themes = ['theme_one', 'theme_two', 'theme_three'];

themes.forEach(function(theme){
    gulp.task(theme, function(){
        require(__dirname+'/themes/'+theme+'/gulp-tasks.js');
        gulp.run('default'); // all theme gulpfiles need a default task
    });
});
```

I see though that gulp.run is deprecated. How should I restructure this to avoid using gulp.run?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use gulp to run various gulp tasks, you can just do `cd themes/theme_one/ && gulp` or write a program to do that without using gulp.

```
var path = require('path');
var process = require('child_process');

var themeDir = process.args[0] || 'theme_one';
var directory = path.join(__dirname + '/themes/' + themeDir);

process.exec('cd ' + directory + ' && gulp', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(stderr);
        console.log('err');
    } else {
        console.log(stdout);
    }
});
```

So you can run this using `node index theme_two`.

Answer (score 0):

### Use a gulp task for each theme

You can write your gulpfile and use a task for each process you want.

For example:

```js
// setup requires ...

gulp.task('theme_1', function () {
  return gulp.src( '/theme/1/*/**' )
  .pipe(zip('theme_1.zip'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('theme_2', function () {
  return gulp.src( '/theme/2/*/**' )
  .pipe(zip('theme_2.zip'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['theme_1','theme_2']);
```

You can run your theme task by simply typing:

```
gulp theme_1
// or
gulp theme_2
```

Run all your theme tasks by default by just typing `gulp`